# How to render code in phalcon view

Tags: php, phalcon

```
$view->start();
$view->render("products", "list");
$view->finish();
```

above is show how to render from a file, I wonder is it possible to render a string/code with this method?

```
$view->start();
$view->renderstring("<?php echo $this->url->get('users/list') ?>");
$view->finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'setContent' to set the view content:

```
$view->setContent('<h1>hello</h1>');
```

But this functions receives the final content to the view. So to do the example you gave the correct use would be:

```
$output = 'The link is: <a href="'.$this->url->get('users/list').'">link</a>';
$this->view->setContent( $output );
echo $this->view->getContent();
```

Comment: vhbmsp, the reason i would like to use view to render is because of it could DI the Url